# Not able to charge iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, charging

I have already tried more than 5 chargers but still my iPhone 5 is not getting charged. If I buy a new charger then it works fine for a week. Why is this occurring and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 7):

Some iPhone 5 are eligible for a free battery replacement. Maybe that is related to your issue?

> Apple has determined that a very small percentage of iPhone 5 devices
>   may suddenly experience shorter battery life or need to be charged
>   more frequently. The affected iPhone 5 devices were sold between
>   September 2012 and January 2013 and fall within a limited serial
>   number range.

You can test if your phone is eligible, on [this website](https://www.apple.com/support/iphone5-battery/).

Comment: that is the most fortuitous & timely piece of information I've had all year. My partner just this morning complained her phone had switched off at 35% remaining charge & we were hoping it wasn't going to an early grave. Thanks to your link, I discovered it's eligible under that replacement scheme.

Answer (score 4):

Before checking for a battery replacement, I would clean the connector of the iPhone. Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghQHYV7sszY) (I will also work for an iPhone 5)

I had this problem and it solved it. If this doesn't work, go with [jherran's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179296).

Good luck

Comment: I had this issue. Used a safety pin and removed a frankly astonishing quantity of compacted dust. It has worked perfectly since then.

Comment: @MJeffryes: someone in the Apple store showed me this with an iPhone 5 I was recycling. I’d been struggling to charge it for weeks. I felt pretty dumb. The SIM removal tool that comes with iPhones works well too.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a thought but since a new charger works for a week or so perhaps the issue is not the phone or the charger the outlet you're using if you always use the same one it might be damaging the charger somehow.